# Type '()' cannot conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent' in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to save response from API in CoreData.. (not sure if its best place) but as soon as I am getting response I am trying to save it.

For that I am trying foreach but getting below error.

Need help if where to store core data and if its correct place how to get rid of this error?

Type '()' cannot conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var results = [ResultItem]()
    let coreDM: PersistenceController = PersistenceController()


        func performSearch() {
            guard let gUrl = URL(
                string: "https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks"
            ) else { return }
    
            Task {
                do {
                    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: gUrl)
                    let response = try JSONDecoder()
                        .decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        self?.results = response.data ?? []
                        ForEach(self?.results ?? [], id: \.self) { // error here -- Type '()' cannot conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'
                            coreDM.saveResult(title: $0.title ?? "")
    
                            }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("*** ERROR ***")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Data Model

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Main Object
struct ResponseData: Codable, Hashable {
    let data: [ResultItem]?
}

// MARK: - Result Item
struct ResultItem: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Double?
    var title: String?
}
```

CoreData

```
func saveResult(title: String) {
    let result =  Item(context: container.viewContext)
    result.title = title

    do {
        try container.viewContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }
}

func getResult() -> [Item] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()

    do {
       return try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not that ForEach - it is a container for enumeratable views, you need `container.forEach(...)` or something appropriate like that.

Comment: @Asperi Can you please elaborate .. any code suggestion please? Do you suggestion to make change in save function?

Answer (score 0):

As allready suggested you are using the wrong method here. `ForEach` is  a `SwiftUI` construct that is used for presenting multiple views out of a collection. But you are not presenting any view here so you would need the standard `.forEach`:

```
results.forEach{
    coreDM.saveResult(title: $0.title ?? "")
}
```